# Comparing two Time::Piece objects

Tags: perl, comparison

I experimented with the Time::Piece and Time::Seconds packages and wrote the below script to compare two Time::Piece objects. What I'm trying to do is to determine if the current time of day is before or after a specific time of day. In this case I've set the specific time to be 10:30:00.

I printed out the two Time::Piece values, and from that it looks like the codes to should work, but the result is not I'm expecting.

Could anyone see what's wrong with my codes?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $settDate;
my $time = Time::Piece->new;
my $eod  = Time::Piece->strptime($time->date . "T10:30:00", '%Y-%m- %dT%H:%M:%S');
print "Time is: ${time}, EOD is: ${eod}\n";
if ($time > $eod) {
    print "Yes, we've passed EOD.\n";
    $settDate = $time->strftime('%Y/%m/%d');
} else {
    print "No, we haven't passed EOD yet\n";
    $settDate = ($time - ONE_DAY)->strftime('%Y/%m/%d');
}
print "Default date is: ${settDate}\n";
```

Output shows:

```
Time is: Wed Jul  3 15:44:26 2019, EOD is: Wed Jul  3 10:30:00 2019
No, we haven't passed EOD yet
Default date is: 2019/07/02
```

Comment: What perl version?  What timezone is your local time?

Comment: My perl version is 5.20. Active Perl. I solved my issue by specifying timezone in Time::Piece->strptime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected comparison result is probably due to different *timezone offsets* in `$time` and `$eod` - `Time::Piece->new` yields a local time, while the `Time::Piece->strptime` yields UTC.
The simplest fix would be to always use UTC: replace `Time::Piece->new` with `Time::Piece->gmtime`.

Comment: You can also cause strptime to work in the local time by calling it from a localtime object (it's [kind of a hack](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Time-Piece/issues/44)): `my $time = localtime->strptime(...)`

Comment: Good point! I just note that this doesn't work with a quite old `Time::Piece->VERSION`, e. g. 1.15; it works with e. g. 1.20_01.

Comment: You're exactly right. It is as you said. I sorted out the issue late yesterday but didn't get a chance to come back here to post an update.